# Problem with Ajax in Firefox Browser

Tags: firefox

This is probably a very basic problem, but I am still at a basic skill level. I have started practicing with Javascript and Ajax recently. I use Ubuntu on a Virtual Box virtual computer. I have a LAMP installed on Ubuntu. I use Firefox. I have been following the Ajax For Dummies frameworks and examples. I have done some simple Javascript text-display scripts and they work fine. However, when I tried an Ajax script (attempting to get data from a text file on the local host) it does not work. The text does not appear in the browser with either "onclick" or "onload". I downloaded and tested the example Ajax for Dummies script (ch03/index.html) and that also did not work. Any answers or advice would be more appreciated than you will probably ever know.
Cheers guys,
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to place all data you are trying to access somewhere within /var/www on your server's filesystem, as /var/www is the default root directory for the webserver.

Comment: Cheers guys, they have always been in either /var/www and /var/www/Development. I will keep working on it.

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect you're trying to access something outside of /var/www.  This permission problem is by design.

If you used `ln -s /var/www/Development ~/Development` apache by default won't follow that link.

Answer (score 0):

Re the above permission suggestions, I am trying the scripts with a WAMP server now. The Dummies scripts are now working, but my own scripts are still not. I will continue to keep at it. Andrew